# arrived to a pair of unexpected discoveries

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm wondering if "arrive to a discovery" is okay in the following extract from a CNN story. Did the author of the following passage mean to say "arrived at a pair of ... discoveries"? Is this a figurative usage?

> Zookeepers at the Columbus Zoo and Aquarium **arrived to** a pair of unexpected discoveries Thursday morning: a newborn baby gorilla and the news that its mother wasn’t a male gorilla.

https://edition.cnn.com/2023/07/21/us/columbus-zoo-gorilla-birth-trnd/index.html

The issue is not about "arrive at" or "arrive to" as used literally. It's about an element of surprise (or shock), also found in other phrases:

> After 15 years in a loving relationship, he came home to a note, and his fiancee was gone

> An Arizona resident came home to a bobcat in the dog's bed.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/arrive-at-vs-arrive-to-usage

Comment: @Mari-LouA The link you posted bears little relevance to the question; the usage in question seems to indicate an element of surprise, not interchangeable with "arrive at."

Comment: I disagree, it explains the difference of usage and meaning  between "at" and "to"  but if think there is no relevance then please add that inference IN the question. You have been a member for many *years* now, share your research.

Comment: It explains only the literal usage, as applied to places and scenes. But the usage in question is about an element of surprise, as in "An Arizona resident came home to a bobcat in the dog's bed. "

Comment: Please don't begin a discussion in the comments. Add your reflections *in* your question.

Comment: At wouldn't be correct in either "After 15 years in a loving relationship, he came home **at** a note, and his fiancee was gone" or "An Arizona resident came home **at** a bobcat in the dog's bed." So why do you think they have anything to do with this? It's often hard to articulate why something seems wrong, but you have to if you want a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**arrive to** means "to be greeted by", in the sense that the object of the preposition **to** is what "greets" you when you arrive, "greet" there being used in a figurative sense: what "greets" you is what you encounter upon arrival.

> He arrived to a brass band playing a Sousa march.
>
> He arrived to an empty house.
>
> She arrived to a roomful of kindergartners doing the hokey-pokey.
>
> He expected he would have to stand in the back but arrived to a nearly empty auditorium.

No element of surprise is *entailed*, but since the locution is about what is encountered upon arrival, it is amenable to surprises.

> He expected a roomful of sleepy students and arrived to a roomful of sleepy students.
>
> He expected a delegation offering him a key to the city but arrived to an angry mob.

Comment: Does this use imply an element of surprise?

Comment: I was typing as you were leaving the comment. See the final section.

Comment: Can this type of to-phrase work with other verbs than "arrive"?

Comment: The preposition **to** can be used with many other verbs. *He fell asleep to ambient music and awoke to the sound of a jumbo jet.*

Comment: In the above example, does the to-phrase also mean encountering something"? It seems to imply a cause?

Comment: **awoke to** is similar to **arrive to** in that the object of the preposition is what greets you upon awakening, but with **fell asleep to** the object of the preposition is what accompanies you  or is in your mind as you fall asleep. *The elderly couple danced to a song that was played at their wedding many years ago.*

Comment: Is it okay to say, "I met John to classical music"?

Comment: In the previous examples, the verb's action occurs not all at once but is prolonged:  awoke to, fell asleep to, danced to, arrived to. Your example with **met John to**, if "met"  means "for the first time", is the opposite: the first meeting takes place at a point in time, and it doesn't work, since the object of **to** is something with inherent duration.

Comment: If, however, "met" is being used to mean "had many a rendezvous with"  (*repeated* action in the past) then it would be a bit of a stretch but it could work, though it would be unidiomatic to have a direct object (I met John to...). It could be expressed like this:  *We used to meet once a month at the orchestra hall; we always met to classical music*.

Comment: Is it okay to say, "He studied to classical music"? The action of studying denotes a process.

Comment: @Apollyon  Yes, **studied to classical music** is a perfect example.